# friendly_id gem, smaller hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id

Given that my slug candidate is `my title`, and it is already used, the slug will return something like: `my-title-49c9938b-ece5-4175-a4a4-0bb2b0f26a27`

Is it possible to have `friendly_id` return a smaller hash? Like: `my-title-705d62eea60a`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that case you can create your own method, which you can pass then to `friendly_id`. There you can define what are going to be the combinations that FriendlyId will use in order to assign a unique identifier to your record as a slug.

For example:

```
friendly_id :column_candidates, use: :slugged

def column_candidates
  [
    :name,
    [:name, :another_column],
    [...more columns combinated as a fallback]
  ]
end
```

If FriendlyId can't create a unique record (by slug) after every combination of columns in `column_candidates` is evaluated, then it's going to append a UUID anyway.

You're free to add the objects you want to `column_candidates`, being strings, procs, lambdas or symbols. Also the method name doesn't have to be exactly that, you can modify it as needed.

As a last resource, and if a unique identifier can't be created, you can rely on creating your own short and always able to not be unique hash using `Digest::SHA1`:

```
...
[-> { Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(name).chars.sample(6).join }]
```

Comment: Gotcha. So as one of the candidates, I can create hex digest of length 6. And if that hex digest is already used (very slim chance, but possible), then friendly_id would add an additional hex digest to the end? I'm totally ok with that, just curious if that would be the behavior.

Comment: The hexdigest is the method you're using as a fallback and as a last chance, after that if your record is still not unique by slug, then FriendlyId will append the UUID (notice UUID not the same as hexdigest) as normal.